# Bluetooth speaker is connected but greyed out

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, speakers

I use a bluetooth USB-adapter (v4.0) to conntect JBL-speakers to my Windows-7 PC, but I fail to output any audio via the speakers. (The JBL-speakers work fine on other devices).

My PC detects the speakers and seems to connect. However, once I open the "devices and printers" control panel the speakers are greyed out.

[image]

Moreover, when right-clicking on the speakers and entering "properties>services", an empty list is shown.

[image]

Finally, the speakers do not appear in the "sound" control panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot the issue.

1. Update the latest Bluetooth driver from the device we are streaming from.
2. Open Bluetooth Support Services on our computer.
3. Follow the steps below to pair our computer and speakers via Bluetooth(Maybe the steps are not exactly the same, the approximate step is this).

We can decide to start afresh and delete all Bluetooth devices we do not need and start again.

Make sure we have our computer Bluetooth turned on.

Down in the bottom right tool bar right click on the Bluetooth icon.

Click on Join a Personal Area Network.

Opens a new Window in Devices and printers.

Turn on our Bluetooth Speaker to discover mode.

Click Add a Device.

Our speaker should show up.

Do not click next.

Instead a message should pop up from the toolbar saying a device is asking to connect.

Click this message.

It will then ask you to add a pairing number to connect ( add the default number if our speaker has one refer to manual).

In this case, if it does not come with one so we can put pairing number by ourselves.

If they are paired successfully.Now click on Start - Devices and Printers and we should see the speaker.

Right click it and click control.

Click connect.

4. View if there is any audio via the speakers.